# Copy-Paste rows from one sheet to another comparing cell values to avoid duplicates using AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
function copyRows()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var tarSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MasterDB");
  var lastRow  = srcSheet.getLastRow();
  var Lr       = tarSheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) 
  {
    var cell = srcSheet.getRange("A" + i);
    var val = cell.getValue();
    Logger.log(lastRow)
    
        for(var j=2; j<= Lr; j++)
    
      {
    
        var findstring = tarSheet.getRange("A" + j);
        var find =findstring.getValue();
       // Logger.log(find)
       
      if (val == find) 
       {
        continue;
        }
var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("A" + i + ":T" + i);
            var tarRow = tarSheet.getLastRow();
            tarSheet.insertRowAfter(tarRow);
            var tarRange = tarSheet.getRange("A" + (tarRow+1) + ":T" + (tarRow+1));
            srcRange.copyTo(tarRange);
 }
}
}
```

- Hello ,actually I'm trying copy & paste rows from one sheet to another within the spreadsheet ,but to avoid duplicates ,i'm comparing cell value from column A in both the sheets.

  - column A is having Date & Time Stamp ,which i'm comparing ,if value matches ,then don't copy &if not copy the particular range & paste on 'last row' of Master DB.
  - But with above code its just keep on copying rows multiple times ,i'm not getting where exactly the error is.
  - Please help me with this ,any help will be appreciated ,Thanks in Advance.
  - Sorry ,if i have posted this in a wrong format ,actually i'm new here.

Comment: Take one of the date columns flatten it with map take everyone of those values convert it to a getTime or valueOf then you can do an indexOf with valUeOf the other column and if it’s not -1 then that’s a duplicate.

Comment: Can you share the sheet to reproduce it? Do the values have different formats?

Comment: Hello Cooper ,thank you for your response ,actually just i tried with adding 'getTime' to the variable 'Val' & 'Find' but getting this error - "TypeError: cell.getTime is not a function (line 111, file "test11")" ,can you please help me with this.

Comment: hello Kessy ,here is the link for the sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lEAlkVWyOUMJLBRtIgDfQ5fSNUOwVCrTTAeTRxZwAdU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function copyRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName("MasterDB");
  var srg=ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow()-1,ssh.getLastColumn());//assume 1 header row
  var svs=srg.getValues();
  var trg=tsh.getRange(2,1,tsh.getLastRow()-1,1);//assume 1 header row
  var tvs=trg.getValues().map(function(r){return new Date(r[0]).valueOf();});
  svs.forEach(function(r,i){
    //if it is not in the target then append it to the target
    if(tvs.indexOf(new Date(r[0]).valueOf())==-1) {
      tsh.appendRow(r);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello Cooper ,you are amazing!! its working so good,thank you so much ,I've multiple sheets like 'Form Responses 1',2,3... ,i'll add a for loop just before your code to select sheets one by one. Again thank you so much ,i was trying this from past 2 days. :)